# Use variable from self C++

Tags: c++, function, object, this, self

I'm trying to create a small class that creates "dots" and calculates the distance between them. I first create two "dot"-objects and then pass the second one as an argument to a function contained in the first dot. This gives me access to the coordinates of the second dot, however I don't really get how I'm supposed to get the coordinates of the first dot - the one that receives the second dot as an arg. I figured it would look something like this, but apparently not:

## .h

```
class Punkt{ //"Punkt" = swedish for "dot"

private:
    int x, y;

public:
    //Konstruktor
    Punkt(int firstX, int firstY): x(firstX), y(firstY){};

    //Setters and getters
    int getX(){return x;}

    void setX(int newX){x = newX;}

    int getY(){return y;}

    void setY(int newY){y = newY;}

    //Avstånd till annan punkt
    double distance(Punkt annanPunkt);
};
```

## .cpp

```
#include "punkt.h"
#include <cmath>

double distance(Punkt annanPunkt){ //"annanpunkt" = "other dot"
    return sqrt(pow((annanPunkt.getX() - self.getX), 2) + 
    pow((annanPunkt.getY() - self.getY, 2))
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated note: "point" is a more usual translation than "dot" in this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you have declared `distance` as a member function, so its definition needs to be in the `Punkt` scope:

```
double Punkt::distance(Punkt annanPunkt){
```

Second, you probably don't need a copy of the argument. Pass a `const` reference:

```
double Punkt::distance(const Punkt& annanPunkt){
```

As for accessing your own data members in the function, you can access them by name (`x` or `y`):

```
annanPunkt.getX() - x), 2)
```

Alternatively, `this->x`, `getX()`, `this->getX()` etc. I find using `this` everywhere too verbose.

Note that you will need to make your getters `const` though:

```
int getX() const {return x;}
```

or remove them entirely: if you have no invariants to maintain, it *may* make sense to use public data members.

Note: I would probably make `distance` a non-member function:

```
double distance(const Punkt& a, const Punkt& b);
```

Comment: Pass by value could perform better if placed in the header (more options for a compiler to optimize)

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks a lot :)! Why do you make the getters const? And what do you mean with the last part you said?

Comment: @AxelKennedal-TechTutor because the getters do not, and should not, modify your instance. Also, if they are not `const`, you cannot call them on a `const` instance or via a `const` reference or pointer. For the last part, there should be no difference between the points, `distance` should treat them equally. `a.distance(b);` has an asymmetry: only `a` has to be a `Punkt`, `b` can be any expression that yields a `Punkt`. So I prefer `distance(a, b);`.

Comment: @Erbureth Can you give a link that would explain that? I mean, if _we actually do need a copy_ - then yes. But we do not need a copy here.

Comment: @juanchopanza What would be the disadvantage of removing all occurrences of "const"?

Comment: @AxelKennedal-TechTutor You couldn't call non-const methods in places where you need constness, you couldn't bind temporaries to references, you'd have users of your code scratching their heads wondering why things that should be const aren't, and your code could not be used inside const-correct code.

Answer (score 1):

First, the function definition needs to qualify the name, to indicate that it's defining the member function rather than a separate non-member function:

```
double Punkt::distance(Punkt annanPunkt)
       ^^^^^^^
```

Within the function, members can be accessed directly (e.g. `getX`), or via `this` (e.g. `this->getX`). Note that `this` is a pointer, hence `->` rather than `.`

`getX` is a function, so you'll need to add `()` to call it and get the value.

Finally, you need to take care that the parantheses are in the right place, and end the statement with `;`

Putting it all together, this should work:

```
double Punkt::distance(Punkt annanPunkt){
    return sqrt(pow(annanPunkt.getX() - this->getX(), 2) + 
                pow(annanPunkt.getY() - this->getY(), 2));
}
```

You can remove `this->`, or even access `x` and `y` directly, if you like brevity.

Answer (score 0):

In **C++** in class member function you have access to all members of a class:

```
double Punkt::distance( Punkt annanPunkt) {
      // ^ note: distance is member function of Punkt class 
    return sqrt( pow( ( annanPunkt.getX() - x), 2) + 
                                         // ^  this object x coordinate
    pow( ( annanPunkt.getY() - y, 2))
                            // ^  this object y coordinate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have `self` but `this`, and in methods you can refer to members without any additional syntax, so you can use:

```
double distance(Punkt annanPunkt){ //"annanpunkt" = "other dot"
    return sqrt(pow((annanPunkt.getX() - getX()), 2) + 
    pow((annanPunkt.getY() - getY(), 2))
}
```